# Rank, invertibility and solution spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-verification, matrix-rank

Let A and B be two matrices of the same order. Let's assume that ρ(B)=ρ(AB) (ρ=Rank).

Which of the following two statements are correct or incorrect?

1. A is invertible
2. The solution space of $AB\mathbf x=\mathbf0$ is equal to the solution space of $B\mathbf x=\mathbf0$.

My answer is "incorrect" to 1): I see no theoretical reason to assume it's correct, and I have found a counterexample. Yet I believe 2). to be correct. If A were invertible it would be very easy to prove this, but as it is not I am looking for the proper evidence.

Can anyone help out?

Thank you!

Comment: What does $\rho$ stand for? Rank? Spectral radius?

Comment: Rank, let me edit...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of the following, which is not too hard to prove: $$ \text{N}(B) \subseteq \text{N}(AB) $$ (null space of $B$ is a subset of the null space of $AB$) and combine it with the rank-nullity theorem.

Comment: Thank you! I've done what you suggested, with the following result: I am able to prove that $N(B) \subseteq N(AB)$. So now I need to prove that the dimensions are equal, so that I can prove that they are equal. But I am wondering if my interpretation of the rank-nullity theorem is correct (I am confused because it's the first time I am applying it to a null space): dimP(ABx=0)=dimKer(ABx=0)+dimIm(ABx=0)
vs.
dimP(Bx=0)=dimKer(Bx=0)+dimIm(Bx=0). The dim of the images are 0, and the dimP(ABx=0)=dimP(Bx=0) because of them having the same rank?

Comment: @dalta the solution space of $Ax=0$ **is** the null space of $A$ which is also the kernel of $A$ when $A$ is considered as a linear transformation...

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**
Try with simple examples. For $2 \times 2$ matrices, you've already figured out that if the rank is $2$, then $A$ is invertible, and the claim is true. The same is true if the rank is zero. That leaves rank 1 matrices to investigate. So look at some examples.

For instance, here's a rank-1 $ 2 \times 2$ matrix $B$: 
$$
\pmatrix{1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0}
$$

If you pick $A = B$, then the ranks of $AB$ and $B$ are the same, and the solution space of $ABx = 0$ is the same as the solution space of $Bx = 0$, which suggests that maybe "2." is true. But that's not a lot of evidence. What other simple $2 \times 2$ rank-1 matrices can you think of? Try a few.

Also: think about what $B$ does as a linear transformation -- I mean geometrically what it does. Then play some more.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, John! I will play around with it, as you suggested. Is there any algebraic evidence, though?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "algebraic evidence", I'm afraid. The key point of this exercise is for you to gain some intuition about what rank does and does not tell you, and having me give you the answer won't help, so my hint is where my help stops.

Comment: OK, I understand… Thanks!